# How to render preview image of a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

net app i want to list some websites with respective dynamically captured site image.Show me some way with C#...

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

http://www.codeproject.com has an article and [source code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webpage_thumbnailer/Thumber_src.zip) on a [Webpage thumbnailer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webpage_thumbnailer.aspx) that will get you up and running.

You can easily modify the source to specify the size of viewport that you would like to capture with, and whether you want a screenshot or a full-height grab.

Comment: both links on that page for the download are broken im afraid

Comment: @PaulStack: thanks - I had bookmarked those a while ago, too bad they are dead. I have updated my response.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you are looking for :

http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_Dynamic_Thumbnail_Creation.aspx

Another one :

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/283.aspx

Comment: Those links demonstrate creating a thumbnail from an image, not from a web site URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can try appending the HTML response of the site to a Literal,

```
    string SiteHtml = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("specify the url here");//Get response to a string
    ltrlSite.Text = SiteHtml; //Assign it to a literal
```

Check this [link](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Get-Web-Site-Thumbnail-Image.aspx)  also.